# Django project run manage.py results in no module named django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv, manage.py

I was working on a django project served as a backend for a small personal site, the built-in localhost server by django runs smoothly until I accidentally removed the app execution alias of python in windows 10(It just happened after done that, might not be the culprit). the situation is that when I use manage.py, it always results in a **no module named "django"**

```
(venv) C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign>manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHO
NPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I tried to resolve it a bit and was only baffled to find the terminal, with which the venv had already been activated, was always being attached to the system-wise python when running which has no django installed in it. The following is python console from venv:

```
(venv) C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign>python
Python 3.8.9 (tags/v3.8.9:a743f81, Apr  6 2021, 14:02:34) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(*sys.path, sep='\n')

C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\venv\Scripts
C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign
C:\Users\hongl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.zip
C:\Users\hongl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs
C:\Users\hongl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib
C:\Users\hongl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\venv
C:\Users\hongl\PycharmProjects\fluentdesign\venv\lib\site-packages
```

I just want to know what happened to the django built-in server by manage.py, why can't i run it with the python in venv which has every necessary packages installed instead of system-wise python?

Comment: I just tried ```python manage.py runserver``` which works, but I am still curious why I can run ```manage.py runserver``` without ```python``` prefix before the situation and now I have to type in python

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment, but I'll post as an answer though I'm not sure this will fix your problem.

Are you positive that Django is install on your venv? try `pip list` or `pip3 list` (depending on system) if django doesn't pop up in that list you may need to install it.

If you're using pycharm you can use a visual interface to modify your venv [see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html?keymap=primary_windows#env-requirements)

Comment: Yes, I'm using pycharm and created the venv through it's built-in tool.